# zoom/pan/scroll force directed network in amcharts4 library

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I want to use amcharts4 to display a network with a huge number of parent nodes and even more child nodes. I took one of the examples found on the amcharts website and increased the number of child nodes on multiple parent nodes. The nodes expand to a point where they bounce off the browser screen and become unreachable. I am a looking for a way to navigate the network by zooming and panning in order to reach the nodes that are outside of the browser page.

I found similar questions on stackoverflow but they were mainly related with XYCharts and maps where ZoomControl was used on the chart/map object and the zoom property was enabled. I couldn't use this method on the force directed diagram element that I have in my code.

Kindly help me out if you know of a way to navigate the force directed diagram either by mouse wheel scrolling and clicking to pan or using the keyboard. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is what the code and output look like : 
https://codepen.io/hichd/pen/ewpoVX

Comment: Hello, did you came up with solution for this? I am also trying to find out solution, but so far with no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not figure out a way for how to zoom/pan with amcharts, I ended up using 3djs instead.

Comment: Would you provide me your code if it is possible? If I would end up using it I would pay for it of course.

Answer (score 0):

`networkSeries.maxLevels = 1;` is the only thing I could think of as I did not come across anything that lets you navigate or pan force-directed graphs.`maxLevels` will reduce the space occupied but it still doesn't answer the question

Comment: It does tidy up the graph space indeed, thank you! I do still need to figure out the zoom/navigation situation.